# want to insert duplicate data in mysql table with new relations id's

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

I have a table with columns ID, tag_ID, W_ID
and data is in below format

```
ID, tag_ID, W_ID
1    25      124
2    25      128
3    25      135
4    25      189
5    25      254
```

Now I want to insert `tag_ID = 28` with all `w_ID` which have `tag_id = 25` and also want to keep existing data

The new data should be like this

```
ID, tag_ID, W_ID
1    25      124
2    25      128
3    25      135
4    25      189
5    25      254
6    28      124
7    28      128
8    28      135
9    28      189
10   28      254
```

Please tell me how to do it with phpmyadmin

Comment: How is the `id` column defined? Is it auto incrementing?

Comment: yes ID is auto incrementing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an insert-select statement with the literal 28 to generate this data:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(tag_id, w_id)
SELECT 28, w_id
FROM   mytable
WHERE  tag_id = 25
```

Comment: Thanks it is the best way to get it

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into tableName(tag_ID,W_ID) 
 select 28,W_ID from tableName where tag_ID=25
```